# Cannot read property 'column_number_data' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, datatables, yadcf

I am using the datatables.net and the yadcf plugin in my angular application. The data is loaded via an ajax request. Now the first time the page loads everything works fine. When I then click into a different page and then come back to the first page, then I get the below error message. If I do a ctrl + F5 to force a refresh then everything works again. Any idea what is causing the second load to throw the below error?

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'column_number_data' of undefined
    at Array.<anonymous> (datatables-angular.js:1313)
    at wb (datatables-angular.js:39)
    at ca (datatables-angular.js:39)
    at L (datatables-angular.js:27)
    at ra (datatables-angular.js:44)
    at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (datatables-angular.js:91)
    at Function.m.extend.each (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2)
    at m.fn.m.each (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2)
    at p [as dataTable] (datatables-angular.js:80)
    at bindData (SalesReports.js:174)
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be related to the fact that on both pages the ID that was created for the dataTable had the same name. I changed the name on one of them and everything worked again.